# FFmpeg could not read existing .bmp frame sequence to make .avi file; What is wrong?

Tags: ffmpeg

Assume current directory contains files in .bmp format, named IMG_0000.bmp, IMG_0001.bmp, and so on. I need to make avi file from them, threating them as a frames. FFmpeg gives me an error, and i could not understand what is wrong. I've got following error message:

```
D:\WORK\MyFrames>"C:\Users\Den\Downloads\ffmpeg-latest-win32-static\ffmpeg-201 30928-git-c461265-win32-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i d:\WORK\MyFrames\IMG_%4d.bmp
 -r 4 -vcodec h264 -y out.avi
ffmpeg version N-56715-gc461265 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers built on Sep 28 2013 18:02:00 with gcc 4.8.1 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
libavutil      52. 46.100 / 52. 46.100
libavcodec     55. 33.101 / 55. 33.101
libavformat    55. 18.104 / 55. 18.104
libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
libavfilter     3. 88.100 /  3. 88.100
libswscale      2.  5.100 /  2.  5.100
libswresample   0. 17.103 /  0. 17.103
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[image2 @ 022cfa60] Could find no file with path 'd:\WORK\MyFrames\IMG_%4d.bmp
' and index in the range 0-4
d:\WORK\Serega28-3\IMG_%4d.bmp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Welcome to [so], part of [the Stack Exchange network](http://stackexchange.com). Stack Overflow is generally for questions on using software that isn't related to programming - if you're looking for help on how to use a command line application, your question is most likely to be better off on [su], a site for general computing questions on hardware and software.  To learn more about [so], visit the [About] page.  Thanks!

Comment: plz just give a short answer instead on closin/bannin/jammin please. that will be cosidered far more constructive and appropriate for a developers Q'A network !!

Comment: I understand that you simply want an answer to your question. However, the entire point of having separate for different types of questions is to ensure that we don't just get questions on everything and everything, which would make it much more difficult to find things of interest in that field.  Jeff Atwood, founder of Stack Overflow, gave an explanation as to [why don't we have one site for everything](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/why-cant-you-have-just-one-site). It would be appreciated if you could take a few minutes to help those who take the time to answer questions like yours.

Comment: I agree. I want $100,000 but nobody wants to give it to me because of people's outdated ideas of "property".

Comment: @Qantas 94 Heavy Later on, in 2017th, i've got your point :) In an effort, i have spared some time, editing this answered question, in order to make it fit some site standarts.

Comment: @Pekka 웃 You could mine/buy some bitcoin then, and just wait 3-7 years until it will cost $100000 =) Property **amount** could remail almost unchanged, just its price will grow, and deflation will work fine for your case. This is called long-term investement, and this could be one of quite easy way (as any pyramide it needs only early investement) of achieving your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error message say that ffmpeg cannot find your input file sequence.

how are they numbered ? if they are named 'IMG_0001.bmp' etc... you have to use:

```
 fmpeg.exe" -r 4 -i d:\WORK\MyFrames\IMG_%04d.bmp -vcodec h264 -y out.avi
```

Comment: Ah, %04d instead of %4d. Thanks a lot!